# How to select children of elements in an .each loop using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the `<img>` tags within each of my `<a>` tags that have the class name `customurl`.

I know that I can do this on one `<a>` like this:

```
$(".customurl img");
```

But I'm trying to work out what the syntax is in an `.each` like so:

```
$(".customurl").each(function(i)
{
    var t = $(this);

    // select child <img> within t
    // (for this iteration)
});
```

Here's a HTML snippet for further clarification:

```
<a class="customurl"><img src="blah" /> Some text</a>
<a class="customurl"><img src="blah" /> Some text</a>
<a class="customurl"><img src="blah" /> Some text</a>
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify why you can't use `$(".customurl img").each()`? If you need parent and child, you could use that and then get the anchor parent with `$(this).parent()`.

Comment: Ah, that's a good solution too. Though it seems messier, especially if I wanted to make changes to future additions into the **a**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the .find('')

```
$(this).find('img')
```

or

```
t.find('img')
```

or this also works using the second param of .each():

```
$(".customurl").each(function(i, elem)
{
    $(elem).find('img')
```

If you only want the first image (assuming you have more than one):

```
$(this).find('img:first')
```

or

```
$(this).find('img:first-child')
```

Comment: And that returns the DOM object so that I can apply normal function and stuff to it right? ie t.find('img').attr("src", "something.jpg")

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```
$(".customurl").each(function(i)
{
    var t = $(this).children('img');

});
```

or if you're going to ensure no text nodes (including whitespace) before the image:

```
$(".customurl").each(function(i)
{
    var t = $(this.firstChild);

});
```

...But if you're just going to run jQuery methods, they iterate for you:

```
$(".customurl > img").attr(/*...*/);
```

This will apply the [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method  to each element in the result.

Also, some methods like `.attr()` will accept a callback as an argument.

```
$(".customurl > img").attr('src', function(i,src) {
     // give each <img> a calculated value for its src
    return 'some_new_value_' + i;
});
```